# Joining two tables through a join in an already existing MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a structure something like this of my two tables:

z_notes:

```
| i_resident_id | resident_fname | resident_lname | i_communication_log | facility_id | dt_note_created |
```

user_roles:

```
| fk_role_id | fk_user_id |
```

The query that is meant to run on z_notes is working fine and perfectly well. Here it is.

```
"SELECT `i_resident_id` AS ID, resident_fname AS FirstName, `resident_lname` AS LastName, 
                        SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Critical_Notes, 
                        SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Routine_Notes,
                        SUM(1) AS Total_Notes
                        FROM z_notes
                        WHERE dt_note_created > '$from'
                        AND dt_note_created < '$to' AND
                        facility_id = '$facility_id'
                        GROUP BY v_resident_fname 
                        ORDER BY Total_Notes $asc_des";
```

This returns:

```
ID |    FirstName |     LastName |  Critical_Notes |    Routine_Notes |     Total_Notes
```

Now this is where i need a join in the query above. This is how the foreign key is worked out:

`i_resident_id` in `z_notes` which links to `fk_user_id` in `user_roles`

Hence, those residents (`i_resident_id`)  whose role i.e. `fk_role_id` == 4 should be excluded from the query. That is, There needs to be more in Where clause which should be something like `i_resident_id` which is equal to `fk_user_id` has a column `fk_role_id` in its table which should not be '4'.

Your input will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT `i_resident_id` AS ID, resident_fname AS FirstName, `resident_lname` AS LastName, 
                        SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Critical_Notes, 
                        SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Routine_Notes,
                        SUM(1) AS Total_Notes
                        FROM z_notes
                        LEFT JOIN user_roles ON z_notes.i_resident_id = user_roles.fk_user_id
                        WHERE dt_note_created > '$from'
                        AND dt_note_created < '$to'
                        AND facility_id = '$facility_id'
                        AND user_roles.fk_role_id != 4
                        GROUP BY v_resident_fname 
                        ORDER BY Total_Notes $asc_des";
```

I just did you said, added a join and a where clause

Comment: @leedz Glad to help. Don't forget to mark the best answer as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark next to it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT `i_resident_id` AS ID, resident_fname AS FirstName, 
`resident_lname` AS LastName, 
SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Critical_Notes, 
SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Routine_Notes,
SUM(1) AS Total_Notes
FROM z_notes
LEFT JOIN user_roles ON (z_notes.i_resident_id = user_roles.fk_user_id )
WHERE dt_note_created > '$from'
AND user_roles.fk_role_id !=4
AND dt_note_created < '$to' AND
facility_id = '$facility_id'
GROUP BY v_resident_fname 
ORDER BY Total_Notes $asc_des
```

OR directly put your != to condition in ON clause

```
SELECT `i_resident_id` AS ID, resident_fname AS FirstName, 
`resident_lname` AS LastName, 
 SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Critical_Notes, 
SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Routine_Notes,
SUM(1) AS Total_Notes
FROM z_notes
LEFT JOIN user_roles ON 
(z_notes.i_resident_id = user_roles.fk_user_id  AND user_roles.fk_role_id !=4 )
                        WHERE dt_note_created > '$from'

                        AND dt_note_created < '$to' AND
                        facility_id = '$facility_id'
                        GROUP BY v_resident_fname 
                        ORDER BY Total_Notes $asc_des
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to answer my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with a subquery

```sql
SELECT `i_resident_id` ID, 
        resident_fname FirstName, 
        `resident_lname` LastName, 
        SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Critical_Notes, 
        SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Routine_Notes,
        SUM(1) AS Total_Notes
  FROM z_notes
 WHERE dt_note_created > '$from'
   AND dt_note_created < '$to'
   AND facility_id = '$facility_id'
   AND i_resident_id NOT IN 
       (
         SELECT DISTINCT fk_user_id
           FROM user_roles
          WHERE fk_role_id = 4
       )
 GROUP BY v_resident_fname 
 ORDER BY Total_Notes $asc_des
```

Comment: I used kaola_dev`s answer but your seems to make sense as well. I want to upvote but can`t due to lack of reputation, will do it as soon as i get some reputation on board.